Does vanguard charge fees for the ETF's that are contained in their ready-made portfolios?
The ETF VDGR is a ready-made portfolio provided by vanguard. It contains other ETF's provided by vanguard to create a diverse portfolio. VDGR charges an annual fee of 0.27% p.a and VAS is the largest holding in the portfolio and it charges a fee of 0.16% p.a.
Am I being charged fees twice for that percentage of the holding? 0.27% for all of VDGR and 0.16% for the part that's VAS.
Or does VDGR just use the products that are listed inside VAS and the only fee I'm being charged is the 0.27% p.a?
I can see these fees seem quite nominal but over the very long term I understand that they can add up.
